# How to Measure Oven to Buy New One

Tags: oven

What is considered the correct oven width?

Oven niche width is 22"

Oven width protruding is 24"

Model 700.3047901

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "protruding."  In the U.S. at least, stoves (with oven below) are almost all of a standard size.  I suggest you start by looking at some product descriptions online.

Comment: Model number? Sounds like you're talking about built-ins, if so you need the installer's manual. The doors on free standing ovens is usually exactly the same width as the enclosure. And they usually stick out (depth) ~2" in front of the counter top, the same as a built-in will from the cabinet. It's a question of if you want a 'reveal' on the stiles of the cabinet; a 24" cab will have none. A 26" with a 22" hole in it would have a 1" reveal on both sides.

Comment: Size of existing hole and width of the stiles? 22" hole and 2" stiles is a 26" cab, and would give you that 1" reveal. But it'd also fit in a 24" with 1" stiles, it just had better not be next to something else that needs clearance to open or also has no reveal.

Comment: Typical widths are 24", 30", 36", with the width listed **including** the walls of the cabinet. But there are sometimes oddball sizes (like the original oven in my house). Take a look at the manual for a possible **new** oven and see what it says for installation/specifications and compare that to what you have now. **Or** post the model # of the existing oven here and if it is not super-old we can figure it out from that.

Comment: I have difficulty finding model number and manual. This was purchased 10 years ago. Will try to search again.

Comment: Model # is typically on a small metal plate (could be plastic, but with ovens often metal for durability) visible on the frame when the door is open. Except of course when they bury it behind some removable part... Start with what brand it is and a picture if you can.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Model 700.3047901, Kenmore

Comment: Providing a picture or two of the existing installation with a tape measure in place showing the dimensions would help a lot. In particular, show the width and the cabinet faces next to the oven.

Comment: I will do this soon

Comment: 700.3047901 doesn't seem to be the right number, because the only hit from Google **is this question**!. Maybe that's a serial number?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I shall check again.

Answer (score 1):

The niche width is usually the width of the opening the oven will fit into.  If you have a niche width 22", the oven you purchase would have to be smaller so it fits into the cabinet/space. The oven protruding width = 24" would be the width of the oven door which is usually 2" wider than the oven.

Oven depth is how far the oven will stick out from the wall. A common notation would be: oven depth = 22", protruding depth = 24". The extra two inches is for the handles and knobs that stick out from the front. Hope this helps.

Comment: This sort of helps. When I mean protruding, I mean the fixtures of the oven protruding outside. When I measure width of oven door, it is 24", but when I measure niche it fits into, it is 22 (or maybe 22.5", because other end of niche is covered by the oven itself)

Comment: I think most ovens have a wider door than actual oven width. The niche width is the really important measurement because that what the oven has to fit in between.

Comment: @Marium You'll want to measure the outside dimension of the actual oven you're replacing. You may also want to carefully look at the cabinets on either side of the oven to see if they have wider stiles than elsewhere in your cabinets. If they do, that indicates that the gap between the cabinets is wider than this oven and you could replace it with a slightly wider one (1-2" most likely) and still have space between the cabinets.

Comment: I will do this soon